# How can add manually api folder nextjs project?

Tags: api, next.js, next-router

I have trouble with api router at Nextjs project.
First I am install nextjs project [image]

I want project structure like image bellow, but I does not have api folder. Then, I am change "Use app Router" is true, but project structure is not my expectation.  [image]

Then, an other solution, I add api folder manually, but when run my project - it doesn't find exactly URL.